# Ember.js Access parent controller within outlet template

Tags: ember.js

I'm pretty new to Ember and am struggling to work this out.

I have a Model, `Huddle`, as well as an associated Controller, the `HuddlesController`. There is a template `huddles.hbs.erb` which contains a single `{{outlet}}`. Under `templates/huddles/` there are two files, grid.hbs.erb and list.hbs.erb. These are rendered into the outlet in `huddles.hbs.erb`.

Now within `huddles.hbs.erb`, I can use an each block that looks like this:

```
{{#each huddle in controller}}
  {{huddle.name}}
{{/each}}
```

And this works as expected, iterating over the collection of Huddles.

However, if I call the same code within `list.hbs.erb` or `grid.hbs.erb`, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: an Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array. You passed <(generated huddles.grid controller):ember405>
```

It seems that I am no longer in the correct scope! How do I access the collection in the parent controller (`HuddlesController` which extends from `Ember.ArrayController`)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per error message you should have a controller named `HuddlesGridController` which extends `Em.ArrayController`. Each route will have its own controller, view and template. This means that `HuddlesController` is used in the resource route (`HuddlesRoute` I'm assuming), but you're an a child route (`HuddlesRoute` I'm also assuming).